# How to filter the result returned by the Query Builder json?

Tags: json, aem

Can someone please help me with how to filter the results returned by the the query builder json servlet? The following is the json response,

```
{
  "success":true,
  "results":2,
  "total":2,
  "more":false,
  "offset":0,
  "hits":[
  {
     "SourceNodePath":"/content/en/events",
     "Status":"COMPLETED",
     "dateRequested":1492325940000,
     "ContentType":"PAGE",
     "SubmissionId":[
        "016192"
     ],
     "SourceLanguage":"en",
     "TargetLanguages":[
        "fr"
     ],
     "dateCreated":1492191038787,
     "dateReceived":1492191112322,
     "Identifier":1492191038787,
     "Initiator":"user",
     "name":"2",
     "Code":"201"
  },
  {
     "SourceNodePath":"/content/en/toolbar",
     "Status":"COMPLETED",
     "dateRequested":1492325940000,
     "ContentType":"PAGE",
     "SubmissionId":[
        "016190"
     ],
     "SourceLanguage":"en",
     "TargetLanguages":[
        "de"
     ],
     "dateCreated":1492190651609,
     "dateReceived":1492190694082,
     "Identifier":1492190651609,
     "Initiator":"foo",
     "name":"1",
     "Code":"201"
  }
 ]
}
```

I'm new to AEM development, is there any way to modify the QueryBuilder JSON Servlet so that it displays the results that has the "Initiator" value as, for example in this case, "user"? The "Initiator" takes the value of the username on AEM Sign In.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your query you can define it like

```
property=Initiator
property.value=user
```

This article outlines all of the options, so take a minute to read through it:
https://docs.adobe.com/docs/en/aem/6-2/develop/search/querybuilder-api.html

I also assume you know you can build queries and see the differences in output with different parameters at this URL: `/libs/cq/search/content/querydebug.html`

Comment: Thank you Shawn. Just went through the article, it has it all. This worked.